# YouTube V3 API (googleapis.com) returns 404?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using the YouTube V3 API in a Discord application. But for some odd reason, this stopped working about 20 minutes ago. The url http://www.googleapis.com returns a "404 Not Found, That's an error", When only half an hour ago it worked!
Does anyone else have this problem? Can I fix it, or is it just Google?

Answer (score 0):

try using https://www.googleapis.com instead of http://www.googlesapis.com

It looks like you got some typo ins the URL. Also, always use https.

Comment: I meant googleapis.com. But it actually doesn't work. Go to http://googleapis.com